My Rspec Test Isn't Following The Range I Specified?
I'm running into trouble with my test. Here it is. It performs a number of inserts into a C database db. The problem is that my test doesn't seem to actually do the number of inserts.
If I specify the range as 1 to 1384. It does 1384 inserts. But after 1384. It only seems to insert 1348 times. I tested this by checking the data table after doing 1384 and 1348 inserts. I did -Wall -Wextra -g3, and nothing went wrong. The C program itself does inserts properly. It seems to be the test not actually doing the number of inserts specified So can can anyone help me find something wrong with the test?
'require rspec'
describe 'database' do
    def run_script(commands)
      raw_output = nil
      IO.popen("./db", "r+") do |pipe|
        commands.each do |command|
          pipe.puts command
        end
  
        pipe.close_write
  
        # Read entire output
        raw_output = pipe.gets(nil)
      end
      raw_output.split("\n")
    end
  
    it 'prints error message when table is full' do
      script = (1..1384).map do |i|
        "insert #{i} user#{i} person#{i}@example\n"
      end
      script << ".exit"
      result = run_script(script) 
      expect(result[-2]).to eq("db > Error: Table full.")
    end
  end

